# Does recursion always improves performance?

Tags: javascript, performance, for-loop, recursion, big-o

Here I have two solutions to find if a srting is a Palindrome. The first one uses Recursion and the second one uses for loop. I am little confused how my code with Recursion would perform vs. the code without recursion. Does the code with Recursion run in O(n) time? If so, how?

```
//Solution using recursion
function isPalindrome(arr) {
    //Runs on first call only
    if (typeof arr === "string"){
        //remove whitespace
        if(arr.match(/\s/)) {
            arr = arr.replace(/\s/g, "");
        }
        //convert to array
        arr = arr.split("");
    }

    //base condition
    if(arr.length === 0 || arr.length === 1) {
        //console.log(true);
        return true;
    } else {
        if (arr[0] !== arr[arr.length - 1]) {
            //console.log(false);
            return false;
        } else {
            arr.shift(); //remove first element
            arr.pop(); //remove last element

            //recursive call
            isPalindrome(arr);
        }
    }
}

//Solution without using recursion
function palindrome(str) {
    var reverseString = [];
    //remove whitespace
    if(str.match(/\s/)) {
        str = str.replace(/\s/g, "");
    }
    //convert to array
    var arr = str.split("");

    for(var i = arr.length; i > 0; i--) {
        reverseString.push(arr.pop());
    }

    if (reverseString.join("") === str) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

console.log(palindrome("racecar"));
console.log(palindrome("si racecar is"));
```

Comment: It's the opposite actually - recursion never improves performance. Why should it: it's just a function call.

Comment: As of complexity: depending on how `arr.shift` is implemented - it might be even `O(n^2)` overall.

Comment: Why not check it yourself?

Comment: @Gantavya: please check my answer - the recursion based one is `O(n^2)`

Comment: Also take a look at tail recursion, a type of recursion most modern compilers can optimize to be as fast as loops.

Comment: @revani most? I wouldn't be that optimistic. Not sure if *any* ES implementation does that.

Comment: Yeah I just checked and sorry, I was wrong. Currenly no ES implementation supports TCO. I stumbled upon some discussions about it but all of them are dropped, developers are not even planning to include that optimization in the near future.
edit: https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=457 v8 seems to be planning to do so.

Comment: @revani: Are you sure they're not planning to include it? I thought it was part of ECMAScript 6.

Comment: @zerkms: To my understanding, there were requirements of ES5 that prevented TCO from being possible, or at least that was the thought at one time. It may be just for the new function syntax, but I'm pretty sure proper tail calls is supposed to be a spec requirement. But I guess technically the optimization part is another issue, though it would seem to naturally follow.

Comment: @sixfingeredman yep, I checked google and found some RFCs. *Personally* I think though that the only proper way to constraint it in the standard is by introducing a new keyword (as for example `clojure` does), not by constraining details of implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering your title question:

No, recursion does not improve performance. It's likely it always makes implementation slower (compared to the *identical* loop based counterpart)

About complexity:

Your recursion solution is likely to be `O(n^2)` since `arr.shift()` operation is likely to be linear.

As of V8 implementation: `array.shift` operation **is** linear. See https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/array.js#L596 and https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/array.js#L313

Alternative implementation:

```
function isPalindromeZ(s) {
    for (var i = 0, len = s.length; i < len / 2; ++i) {
        if (s[i] != s[len - i - 1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

What is good about this implementation compared to yours is that it is `O(1)` by additional memory consumption.

Comment: Hm... O(1)? I think that you mean O(n).

Comment: @Guffa: it performs search in place, so it works on a constant memory size.

Answer (score 1):

No, recursion doesn't improve performance in itself, rather the opposite. The recursive call adds a bit of overhead, so a recursive solution is generally somewhat slower than an iterative solution, if there exists a simple one (as in the example).

Recursion can be used to simplify certain tasks that are nested in nature, which require complex code to be solved iteratively. That is the case where recursion can improve performance, by removing so much complexity that it far outweighs the small overhead that it adds.

The example in your question is not a good example of how to use recursion. It can be used to demonstrate how recursion works, but it can't demonstrate how recursion is used well.

The recursive version does not have an O(n) complexity, closer to an O(n²) complexity. The `arr.shift()` call will move all the items in the array, which mean that each iteration has an inner loop that runs the length of the remaining array.

Also, there is a bug in the recursive version; the last line should be:

```
return isPalindrome(arr);
```

Comment: thanks. Actually, that bug was preventing the printing of true or false on the console.